# How Terraform local-exec works on Concourse?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-step-functions, aws-xray

I used 'null_resource' and pass aws cli to 'local-exec' to update stepfunction:

```
resource "null_resource" "enable_step_function_xray" {
  triggers = {
    state_machine_arn = xxxxxxx
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command     = "aws stepfunctions update-state-machine --state-machine-arn ${self.triggers.state_machine_arn}  --tracing-configuration enabled=true"
  }
}
```

This works fine when I tested via local Terraform, my question is if this will work if I apply Terraform on Concourse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends entirely on if you have the Concourse job configured to use a container image that has the `aws` cli tool installed. If the AWS CLI tool is installed and in the path then the `local-exec` should succeed. If not, then it will obviously fail.

Comment: Is there an example of the container image with aws cli installed?

Comment: I found this:https://hub.docker.com/r/teliaoss/concourse-awscli Should I push this image to ECR and how can I configure on concourse yaml file to tell concourse to use this image?

Comment: @Cecilia what image are you currently using to run the Terraform job? The image you linked won't work for you because you need an image with both Terraform and the AWS CLI installed. Terraform is going to call the AWS CLI when it provisions your `local-exec` resource, and it's going to do that locally, on the same system Terraform is running on, that's what "local exec" means.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that in your local machine, you've already set up the required credentials. So if you simply try it on [Concourse CI](https://concourse-ci.org/) it will fail with an authentication error.

To set it up in Concourse -

1. AWS Console - Create a new IAM user `cicd` with programmatic access only and the relevant permissions. For testing purposes, you can use the `AdministratorAcess` policy, but make sure to make it [least-privileged](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#grant-least-privilege) later on.
2. AWS Console - Create AWS security credentials (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY) for the `cicd` user (save them in a safe place)
3. Concourse CI - Create the [secrets](https://concourse-ci.org/creds.html) `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`
4. Concourse CI - Add `((AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID))` and `((AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY))` [environment variables to your Concourse CI task](https://concourse-ci.org/jobs.html#schema.step.task-step.vars)

I'm sure there are many tutorials about this subject, but the above steps will probably appear in most of these tutorials. Concourse CI should now be able to apply changes on your AWS account.

Comment: Hi I've already setup a pipeline on Concourse, my question is basically focusing on `local-exec` part, I wonder if it will work on Concourse if it works via local Terraform apply? Because when I test locally, it's using windows CMD on my local machine, what it will use if I apply on Terraform? Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Sounds like you need to run it in Concourse to find out. I thought your concern was about running `terraform apply` from a machine that is not your machine